# Three phase power supply for test purposes

Tags: motor, three-phase, alternator

I work in the electrical industry and deal with mainly three phase power.
I'm trying to broaden my knowledge of scopes and power quality and the only time I really have to do this is at work and that then is of course very limited as I have constant projects on the go.
That leaves home........I've decided not to use a VFD as the output isn't great, (I want a pure sine wave as a starting point), and a generator is too noisy.
What I thought was to use a single phase motor connected by a belt to a star connected 3 phase alternator/permanent magnet motor.
The output, (three phases and neutral), will be connected across a CATIII oscilloscope and at times possibly a dummy load together.

What raises my eyebrows is safety. Whilst the 'system output' will not be connected electrically in any way to the electrics in the house, I'll be generating a sort of floating supply so the usual protections might apply in a different way or not at all?

I'd appreciate your comments, thanks.

Comment: Connect N to PE.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 And then use residual current protection.

Comment: Your generator output won't be subject to the nasty 1500 V spikes on mains due to lightning strikes and suchlike that require special measures for safety on mains (X and Y rated caps, double insulation, CATx multimeters). And as Tony says, N to PE, so RCDs will work, and it will limit your max voltage to ground under fault conditions of phase rather than 1.73 phase.

Comment: Hi Neil. You've made a good point with the CATIII thing. I'd not thought broadly about that - I only have CATIII probes anyway so I suppose it's a moot point.

Comment: N to PE, thanks for that. The whole shebang just seemed too easy so I figured I'd be missing something.